# jQuery toggle doesn't work

Tags: jquery, toggle

i like to toggle `.toggle-item-(number here)` with `.link(number here)`. At the beginning all `.toggle-item`s are closed. Only one toggle item should be shown at the same time. Every time a new toggle item opens an other open toggle item should close.

Link with code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/rAUqb/

Why does the jQuery code not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Marc's code so it closes the others when clicking.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[class^=toggle-item]').hide();
    $('[class^=link]').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var x = $this.attr("class");
        var className = '.toggle-item-' + x.replace('link', '');
        $(className ).toggle();
        $('[class^=toggle-item]:not('+className +')').hide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't quite need to be as complicated as this, see my updated code.

Comment: Its not not really complicated. Your updated code does not toggle the same item when clicking on it more than once, altso it does not hide the items on load

Comment: Thank you both - Marc and Contra - both of you contributed to solution

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your code.

You were not getting the number correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[class^=toggle-item]').hide();
    $('[class^=link]').click(function() {
        var x = $(this).attr("class").replace('link', '');
        $('[class^=toggle-item]:not(.toggle-item-'+x+')').hide();
        $('.toggle-item-' + x).toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

The value in x was the full class name ("link1", "link2", etc). I simply stripped out the "link" part to just have the number.

Comment: Thank yo but this code did not close an already open toggle item - any ideas for that?

Comment: Code fixed, toggles current on and off now.

Answer (score 0):

Would the [Jquery accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) not work for you?

Comment: No, because at the beginning no .toggle item should be open

Comment: Check out the `collapsible` option. This will allow for all sections to be closed at once. If it could work for you, its much better than trying to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

use `attr("class")` instead of `attr("classname")`